# Localization in Pinyin with the tone marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, google-translate, cfstring

I am creating an iOS application in which there is a localisation of Pinyin Language. The issue seems to be that I am not getting the perfect translated word like Google Translate is giving.

I am using this piece of code to translate the Chinese characters to Pinyin, but I am not able to get the tone marks which are present in some of the Pinyin characters.

```
NSMutableString *pinyin = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)(pinyin), NULL, kCFStringTransformMandarinLatin, NO);
```

[image: I want to this type of translation]

Thank you

Comment: Looks there is nothing to do with Cloud Translate API technically here...

Comment: @JL-HN I am sorry but i didnt get you properly.. Can you explain a bit more in this reference

Comment: @JL-HN and is there any chance If i have to do like this same to get the same result as Google Translate.